# Is Amazon EC2 recommended for a persistent public facing website?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

My company is about to write a new public facing website in SharePoint (so Windows Server 2008 RC2, SQL Server 2008 RC2, etc) and we're looking at using Amazon EC2 to host it. I've read and been told that instances can disappear (often through user-error, but also in batches), so I'm skeptical that EC2 is the best idea for us.

I've done research on the Amazon AWS site, but must confess that most of the terminology used is confusing, and Googling my questions often brought me here, so I thought I'd ask my questions here too and see if people can advise me.

1) It's critical that our website be available to the public as much as possible (the usual 99.9% up times apply).  The Amazon EC2 Service Level Agreement commitment is 99.95% availability, which is fine, but what happens if we hit that 0.05% scenario? Would our E2 instance be lost? Can these be recovered? If so, what would we need to do to ensure that we recover to a not-too-old version of our site?

2) I've read about Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS), and how this is persist independently from the lifetime of the instance. If I understand right, EBS is like having a hard-drive, so if the instance is lost we can start a new instance using our EBS to recover the latest version, while the 'local instance store' would be lost if the instance is lost as well. Is that right?

3) Are 'reserved instances' a more stable option? i.e. are they less likely to disappear? If they do still disappear, what recovery benefits do they offer, if any?

I know these questions are kinda vague, but hopefully you'll be able to offer a newbie from basic info - enough to point me in the right direction for further, deeper research at least.

Many thanks.

Kevin

Comment: Reserved instances have no advantage to uptime or stability.  All they are is paying less but up-front.  Your instance won't be lost if uptime is less than 99.95, but it'd be like if any other machine was not available.  We host our corporate site on EC2 and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for that, Joe. I read a fair amount on the reserved instances, but couldn't get if there was more to it that just price, and it seems there isn't. Good to know :)

Comment: Amazon EC2 is great. I can certainly do what you describe. Since you're using a Microsoft product, you might also consider Azure, Microsoft's cloud.

Answer (score 5):

We rely on AWS for our webservers. I won't use anything else. They're highly scalable, easily configurable and have an absurd uptime. I've never experienced downtime with them. We've been with them for two years.

Reserved instances are cheaper. Get them if you're planning on having that instance for a while. It's simply a cost/budgeting issue.

Never heard of people losing an EC2 instance.

Not terribly knowledgeable about EBS, but S3 is a good way to back up data.

HTH

EDIT:

Came across some links that might be helpful.  Cheers.

http://techblog.netflix.com/2010/12/four-reasons-we-choose-amazons-cloud-as.html

http://techblog.netflix.com/2010/12/5-lessons-weve-learned-using-aws.html

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/04/working-with-the-chaos-monkey.html

Comment: One note on your instance being lost. You should keep your application in source control and regularly back up your production data. Even the best, most reliable solution doesn't allow you to rest easy without a backup and deterministic deployment script.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Homer. My boss has heard of instances being list, though looking around some more it seems that this is rare, and often user error. It's good to hear that in 2 years you've not seen any such issues.

Regarding backup: Do you take snapshots of the EC2 instance, and if so, where do you store them?

Comment: No, we don't. We don't store any user data on the filesystem. We only store data in the database, which amazon also hosts. We only create images for easy webserver deployment. Our application code is all in source control and can be easily deployed to any server because we have a build script.

Comment: @QMKevin - Found some links that you might be interested in reading. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main design goals of AWS is to make fault tolerant services--that is services that can recover from failures. That is, they design all of their services with the assumption that something will fail in some way at some point, *but* that there will be redundancies and other mechanism in place to *recover* from those inevitable failures.

In the case of storage services like S3 and SimpleDB, this is achieved primarily by replicating your data across multiple nodes (machines) in multiple data centers. So when one node experiences a hardware failure or one data center experiences a power outage, there's no real down time as the replicas can still service the requests. As a consumer, you aren't even aware of the down nodes or data centers.

EC2 is designed to work similarly, but it is not quite as encapsulated as S3 and SimpleDB, so you'll need to plan for a bit of the work yourself. For example, if you need a web service with guaranteed uptime and availablity, you'll want to look into AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancing) service. That way if an instance is down, requests will automatically be routed to other healthy instances. For your data, you can either store it in other AWS services (like S3 and SimpleDB and EBS) which have built-in redundancy or you can build your own solution using similar redundancy techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, C. Dragon. I'll look more into AWS ELB, as a load balanced server could be very useful for us. I've heard reports that SharePoint 2010, if used with high traffic volume, can require rebooting every 3 months or so, so a load balanced system would be useful in that scenario.

I think I'd like to find out more about backups though, especially the idea of off-site (or off-cloud, in this case) backups. Ideally I'd like to backup the entire website on a daily basis, so that if the worst happened, we just re-start a new instance using that backup... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The SLA amounts to none, when we found out that:

1. Instances and EBS volumes DID get lost
2. It takes Amazon more than 2 days to recover from a disaster, and even that not to the full extent

We were the lucky ones, that managed to get back on our feet in less than 2 days. Other companies got stuck with no recovery option.

And what does Amazon recommend? "Don't trust our reliability. Pay for 2 or 3 more copies of your system in different regions, and then you will be safe".

More information can be found here:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/saas/lightning-strike-zaps-ec2-ireland/1382

Answer (score 0):

tldr: AWS is very reliable if you know what you're doing, a bad idea if you don't.

As your unfamiliar with terms here's a very quick  glossary:
AZ - Availability zone, there's several availability zones per region (e.g. 3 in Ireland). They are physical isolated datacentres with different power grids, flood plains etc. But with internal network quality speed connections. It's possible even likely an AZ may become unavailable at some point, I don't think all AZ's in a region have ever been down though.

EBS/Instance Store - These are the two main types of storage available to instance. The best way to describe them is Instance Store is the equivalent to a HDD you have plugged in via sata to your motherboard - its very fast. But what happens if you shutdown your instance (or if the motherboard fails) and want to instantly start on another board? (Amazon completely hides the physical hardware setup) obviously you aren't going to wait for an engineer to unplug a drive from one server and into another so they don't even offer this. Instance store is fast but temporary and tied to the physical machine DO NOT store anything important on it. EBS then is the alternative it is a very low latency network drive that any server can connect to as though it were local. You shut down a server, change the size and restart on a completely different server on the other side of the datacentre (again the physical stuff is hidden), doesn't matter your ebs hasn't gone anywhere (by default theyre also on multiple physical discs).

Commodity cloud hardware - My interpretation of all the 'cloud hardware fails all the time - its really risky and unreliable' is that yes aws hardware is not as reliable as enterprise level components in a managed datacentre. This doesn't mean its unreliable, it just means you should build failure as an option into your design.

First very important thing to note when talking about SLA's is that amazon state very clearly that the SLA ONLY applies if one or more AZ goes down. So if you do not understand how their service works and only build one server in one AZ and a generator or router fails it's your own fault.

As for recovery, that depends - is your entire application state stored on one server - if it is, don't bother with the cloud. If however you can cluster your state on multiple servers, store it in RDS or some other persistent DB. OR if your content changes so infrequently you can utilise periodic copies to s3 storage, you'll be fine. You failure strategy (in order of preference) could be clustered, failover, or auto repair. For the first one you have clustered servers sharing state - it doesn't matter if you lose a server or an AZ. For the second you only have one live server, but if it goes down you have a failover standing by with the same content. Finally with auto repair there's two possible situations - if your data is only on one EBS drive, you could start another instance with the same drive and carry on. But if the EBS drive or AZ fails, you will need to be ready with some snapshot in s3 that a completely fresh instance can copy and start up with.

Reserved instances are no more reliable - they're the same hardware, you're just entering into a contract to say i'll have x machines for y years. Which allows aws to plan better, which is cheaper for you.